# В каком числе определение согласовывается с однородными подлежащими

Tags: согласование

Мой вопрос состоит в следующем:
Пример: "Запрашиваемая(ые) Вами проектно-разрешительная документация, экспертное заключение и иная документация отсутствует."
В каком числе следует употреблять определение "запрашиваемая"?
Возник спор на этом фоне, т.к. я считаю, что данное слово в этом контексте употребляется в единственном числе, т.к. по смыслу ясно, что определение относится ко всем видам документации, и есть одно объединяющее слово "документация", и, при желании, можно написать:" запрашиваемая документация отсутствует". А мой оппонент считает, что здесь идет перечисление разной документации и, соответственно, ставится мн. число. В пример приводит:" купленные мной груша, яблоко, персик". 
Помогите, пожалуйста разрешить данный спор!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласование в единственном числе используется с абстрактными понятиями (что заметно и по примерам Розенталя).
Документы же абстрактными не являются. Правильнее всё же множественное число, но тогда в конце обязательно исправить окончание глагола "*отсутсвовать*" на *-ют*:
*Запрашиваем**ые** Вами проектно-разрешительная документация, экспертное заключение и иная документация отсутству**ют**.*

Именно такое оформление характерно для делового стиля, где преобладает конкретика. Согласование в единственном числе больше характерно для публицистического и художественного.

В примере же "*купленные мной груша, яблоко, персик*" мн. ч. обусловлено не тем, что существительные указывают на разновидность предметов, а тем, что это конкретные существительные, а не абстрактные и что у них разный род. Разновидность всегда присутствует при перечислении.

Comment: Великолепная шуба и шляпка - разве абстрактные существительные?( пример из Розенталя).

Comment: Такое бывает, когда 2 существительных в одном роде. В данном примере мн. плохо звучит. А в примере из вопроса ж. и м.

Comment: Документация - собирательное сущ. Поэтому здесь ед. ч.

Comment: А есть у вас примеры такого собирательного в конце?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, о чем вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Корректные примеры с такими случаями (ед. ч. в конце).

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы, здесь нужно ед. ч. Т.к в данном примере ключевое слово документация. По смыслу ясно, что определение относится ко всем существительным.

Правило таково.

Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме  е д и н с т в е н н о г о  числа:

1) если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: **российская печать, радио и телевидение; подъём нашей техники, науки и культуры; декада норвежской литературы и искусства; создание новой оперы, балета, музыкальной комедии; литературный карьеризм и индивидуализм; школьная успеваемость и дисциплина; в своём изложении и выводах…;**

В примере же "купленные мной груша, яблоко, персик" мн.ч. обусловлено тем, что существительные указывают на разновидность предметов.

См.: [§195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)

Comment: Согласование "*отсутствует*" (ед. ч.) не звучит. Ниже у Розенталя пример: *Машиностроительная и металлообрабатывающая промышленность, **занимающие** (мн. ч.) по числу рабочих первое место среди других отраслей промышленности.* В примере вопроса перечислены конкретные документы, а не абстрактные понятия. Возможно, что множественное число лучше, а в конце исправить на *-ют*.

Comment: @ oleedd, а вы выбераете тот или ной вариант написания только ориентируясь на благозвучность? В данном примере определение относится ко всем сущ-ым. А в вашем примере определение постпозитивно. Об этом и говорит Розенталь. .

Comment: Не только, но в том числе. "*Отсутствует*" - тоже постпозитивный глагол. То есть здесь по обе стороны (*запрашиваемая/ые* и *отсутствует/ют*).

Comment: Поспозитивный глагол, а не определение. Который, кстати, в ед.ч. Но если не согласны, напишете свой ответ.