# Спряжение и безударные личные окончания глаголов

Tags: орфография, глаголы, окончания, спряжение

Первое спряжение — е / ут / ют. Второе спряжение — и / ат / ят.

Глагол «поддерживать». Заканчивается на -ать. В первое спряжение входят все глаголы на -ать, кроме гнать, держать, слышать, дышать. Значит, «поддерживать» относится к первому спряжению. Ставится -е. Но почему «он поддержИт»?

Глагол «заманивать». -ать. Не входит в исключения. Тоже первое спряжение. Ставится -е. Но почему «калачом не заманИшь»?

Глагол «стелить». Все глаголы на -ить относятся ко второму спряжению, кроме брить, стелить, зиждиться, зыбиться. Исключение. Раз это первое спряжение, то ставится -е. Но почему «он стелИт»?

Глагол «мелить». В исключения не входит. Второе спряжение. Ставится -ат или -ят. Но почему «кофе мелЮт»?

Глагол «оканчиваться». -ать. Первое спряжение. Ставится -ут или -ют. Тогда почему «занятия окончАтся»?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм, как ставить окончания в таких ситуациях, а то до разбора правил писала грамотнее. Теперь стопорюсь на каждом глаголе, так как правописание, которое помню чисто визуально, конфликтует с правилами. Я на автомате пишу «окончатся», «поддержит», но не могу аргументировать выбор окончания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша основная ошибка связана с **видовыми парами**, так как  глаголы разного вида могут иметь разное спряжение.

*Заманить — заманивать, поддержать — поддерживать, окончиться* — оканчиваться. Эти пары глаголов относятся ко второму и первому спряжению соответственно.

***Мелить*** — мазать мелом. Есть глагол ***молоть*** — мелет — мелют.

Глагол ***стелить*** (искл) и ***стлать*** относятся к 1-му спряжению: стелет, стелют

Так что классические правила действуют во всех ваших примерах.

Comment: С кем вы тут согласны (сложная тема)? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457780